# Azure Mobile Services use from command line for testing

Tags: mobile, curl, azure, command-line, wget

I have a Windows Azure Mobile Service that works great with the official clients. However, it would be better if I could run my tests from command line scripts without having to write and compile code.

How do I have to parameterize `curl` or `wget` to access the tables and API scripts in my service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one has got some curl calls that help do quick test on my demo mobile services apps...

note the custom header "X-ZUMO-APPLICATION" plus how you configured permissions on tables. the easiest one is to just use the application key.

[Experimenting with Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2012/09/19/experimenting-with-windows-azure-mobile-services.aspx)

Examples:

```
#read table
curl --header X-ZUMO-APPLICATION:{apptoken} https://{servicenamespace}.azure-mobile.net/tables/{tablename}
#invoke API script
curl --header X-ZUMO-APPLICATION:{apptoken} https://{servicenamespace}.azure-mobile.net/api/{scriptname}
```